# Can't change text in .click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have paragraph in html and want to change it's text by click on a button. Text changes sometimes for a second but returns to previous state. I can't understand why.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
         $("#login_error").text('first');
         $("#authorization_button").click(function () {
         $("#login_error").text('second');
       });
});


<p id="login_error"></p>
```

So,  `$("#login_error").text('first');`  works, but  `$("#login_error").text('second');`  doesn't.

Comment: That's probably because your authorization button is triggering form submission, so you're reloading the page and the page will reset. Use `event.preventDefault()` in your click handler.

Comment: can you please post the paragraph html and your full html?

Comment: Are you creating $("#authorization_button") dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a event.preventDefault(); under your button
 so it would look like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#login_error").text('first');
            $("#authorization_button").click(function () {
event.preventDefault();
                $("#login_error").text('second');
            });
```

maybe..